# Disable ANR on Fire TV

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, amazon-fire-tv

Hi there :) I have one simple question. Any know how to avoid or disable ANR error on Amazon Fire Tv? I read to many topic and no found any solution because it Android system case, but maybe. Maybe you know something more information? Best regards! ;)

Comment: Do not tie up the main application thread. This is no different on a Fire TV than it is on any other Android device, though it is possible that Amazon tweaked it somewhat (e.g., how long you tie up the main application thread before the ANR is triggered). Why do you think that the Fire TV is different than other Android devices with respect to ANR behavior?

Comment: I know that. This just question))) This information need not for real project. I am wanna know how do this for self erudition